# How can extract text from pdf to excel

Tags: excel, pdf

I have Scanned Image, I converted it to pdf file, the content of image are rows and columns (table), I want Extract the text from table to excel file, any Idea? any good website or tool or program can I use it

I tried to use a lot of websites to extract text, but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Microsoft Excel? If you do, then first convert the PDF to a JPEG.

And with that, go to Microsoft Excel

- Create a New Document
- Go to the Data Tab
- Choose "Data From Picture"
- Choose Picture From File

[image: Data from Picture button in Excel]

You'll see a couple of instructions. Follow them to complete the process of converting the picture to table.
You'll also have the option of correcting any inaccuracies before adding them to your spreadsheet.

That's all!